# Category/search images not showing in Firefox

Tags: magento2, security, content-security-policy

I get Content Security Policy errors in Firefox. I have a CSP module that handles this just fine in Chrome, but this remains an issue in Firefox. Are there more steps that have to be taken to make security policies in Firefox?

Comment: Follow this link https://sherocommerce.com/magento-content-security-policy/ Happy coding

Comment: Donor post a link as answer. Answer must have some content